# How to download file that have inconsistent filename

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I'm downloading a file daily from SharePoint site and the code below is working fine. The only thing that I need to figure is how to pass in the filename parameter if the file name is inconsistent.

For example. The file was uploaded daily by someone like this

```
Full-Report-2023-01-10-03.00.13AM.csv

Full-Report-2023-01-09-02.00.43AM.csv

Full-Report-2023-01-08-20.30.53AM.csv
```

I'm supposed to download that file daily, but not sure how to do it if the time is included in the file name.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
function DownloadFile($token, $siteId, $driveId, $filePath, $fileName)
{
    $headers=@{}
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/drives/$driveId/items/root:/$($filename):/content" -Method GET -OutFile $filePath -Headers $headers
}

# Need to fix here
DownloadFile -token $token -siteId $siteId -driveId $driveId -filePath "E:\Log-Files\Latest-Report.csv" -fileName "Full-Report-2023-01-08-20.30.53AM.csv"
```

Comment: Can you list the files in `/root:/` ? If so then you just sort them by date and pick the newest one

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Hi could you please show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`me/drive/root/children` endpoint doesn't support ordering by `createdDateTime` property, so you need to order files by `name` descending, use `$filter` to return only files that start with `Full-Report-` to reduce the number of file to be returned.
You can use `$select` to return only `id` and `name` property. You can return only one item (by using `$top)` which should be the latest file.

```
$latestFiles = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/drives/$driveId/items/root/children?`$orderby=name desc&`$filter=startswith(name,'Full-Report-')&`$select=name,id&`$top=1" -Method GET -Headers $headers
```

So, if you have the following files

```
Full-Report-2023-01-10-03.00.13AM.csv
Full-Report-2023-01-09-02.00.43AM.csv
Full-Report-2023-01-08-20.30.53AM.csv
```

the query above should return only `Full-Report-2023-01-10-03.00.13AM.csv`

Parse the response json `$latestFiles` to get `name` property of the first item.

Now you can call `DownloadFile` and use `name` from the response above for `-fileName`

```
# parse the response json to get name property of the first item
$firstItem = $latestFiles[0] #parse response by yourself
DownloadFile -token $token -siteId $siteId -driveId $driveId -filePath "E:\Log-Files\Latest-Report.csv" -fileName $firstItem.Name
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this but when I run the query it look like it returning multiple item instead of just only one like mentioned. please advice.

Comment: @aasenomad My mistake. There must be a backtick character before $select, $filter, $order and $top, otherwise powershell will handle those parameters as properties. I've updated the answer with the correct URI for Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: Thank you so much for this but by any chance can we filter using if it contain today date in the file name so that it'll not download if the file is not up to date. I'm trying to change startswith to like or contains but still not luck.

Comment: @aasenomad using `contains` instead of `startswith` also doesn't work for me. Looks like `contains` is not supported for this endpoint